# How to make C codes in Tru64 Unix to work in Linux 64 bit?

Tags: c, linux, unix, migration

I wanna know probable problems faced while moving C programs for eg. server process from Tru64 Unix to Linux 64 bits and why? What probable modifications the program would need or only recompiling the source code in new environment would do as both are 64 bit platforms? I am a little confused, I gotta know before I start working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a lot of time in the early 90s (*OMG I feel old...*) porting 32-bit code **to** the Alpha architecture.  This was back when it was called OSF/1.

You are unlikely to have any difficulties relating to the bit-width when going from Alpha to x86_64.

Developers are much more aware of the problems caused by assuming that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void *)`, for example.  That was far and away the most common problem I used to have when porting code to Alpha.

Where you do find differences they will be in how the two systems differ in their conformity to various API specifications, e.g. POSIX, XOpen, etc.   That said, such differences are normally easily worked around.

If the Alpha code has used the SVR4 style APIs (e.g. streams) that you may have more difficulty than if it has used the more BSD-like APIs.

Answer (score 1):

64 bit architecture is only an approximation of the classification of an architecture.

Ideally your code would have used only "semantic" types for all descriptions of variables, in particular `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` for sizes and pointer arithmetic and the `[u]intXX_t` for types where a particular width is assumed.

If this is not the case, the main point would be to compare all the standard arithmetic types (all integer types, floating point types and pointers) if they map to the same concept on both platforms. If you find differences, you know the potential trouble spots.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [64-bit data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) used by both platforms, most 64bit Unix-like OS's use LP64, so it is likely that your target platforms use the same data model.  This being the case you should have few problems given that teh code itself compiles and links.

If you use the same compiler (e.g. GCC) on both platforms you also need not worry about incompatible compiler extensions or differences in undefined or implementation defined behaviour.  Such behaviour should be avoided in any case - even if the compilers are the same, since it may differ between target architectures.  If you are not using the same compiler, then you need to be cautious about using extensions.  #pragma directives are a particular issue since a compiler is allowed to quietly ignore a #pragma it does not recognise.

Finally in order to compile and link, any library dependencies outside the C standard library need to be available on both platforms.  Most OS calls will be available since Unix and Linux share the same POSIX API.